# How to print individual members of a struct

Tags: c, time, struct, printf

I need to print out the current date in the following format : Today is Wednesday - September 7, 2012. I know I will have to use the struct

```
 struct tm* time_info;
```

I can easily accomplish this using strftime(), however, I am tasked to NOT use strftime() and extract members of the struct directly using printf statements. I cannot seem to get it to properly work. Any clues? Here is my current code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <time.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 /* localtime example */
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <time.h>

 int main (void)
 {
 time_t t; 
 char buffer[40]; 
 struct tm* tm_info; 

 time(&t); 
 tm_info = localtime(&t);
 strftime(buffer, 40, " Today is %A - %B %e, %Y", tm_info); 
 puts(buffer); 


  return 0;
}
```

Instead of

```
 strftime(buffer, 40, " Today is %A - %B %e, %Y", tm_info);
```

I need

```
 printf("Today is %s, struct members info in the correct format);
```

Comment: "I cannot seem to get it to properly work" -- What have you tried? The code you posted is irrelevant since it calls strftime. Also, since this is homework, add a homework tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The struct tm has at least these [members](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/basedefs/time.h.html)

```
int    tm_sec   Seconds [0,60]. 
int    tm_min   Minutes [0,59]. 
int    tm_hour  Hour [0,23]. 
int    tm_mday  Day of month [1,31]. 
int    tm_mon   Month of year [0,11]. 
int    tm_year  Years since 1900. 
int    tm_wday  Day of week [0,6] (Sunday =0). 
int    tm_yday  Day of year [0,365]. 
int    tm_isdst Daylight Savings flag.
```

So now you can do e.g.

```
printf("Today is %d - %d %d, %d", tm_info->tm_wday, 
                                  tm_info->tm_mon,
                                  tm->tm_mday,
                                  1900 + tm_info->tm_year);
```

This ofcourse will print out the month and week day as numbers, I'll leave it up to you to create a simple lookup table to get the matching English word. Use an array so you can map e.g. index 0 to "Sunday" , index 1 to "Monday" and so on.

Comment: how about doing this with cout?

Comment: should be `tm_info->tm_mon+1` (the month range is 0-11, January is 0)

Answer (score 2):

You can access individual elements of a struct using the `-> dereferencing operator:

```
printf("Time is %02d:%02d:%02d\n", tm_info->tm_hour, tm_info->min, tm_info->tm_sec);
```

You can find all the required fields of `struct tm` [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/time.h.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass each member of the [`struct tm`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/tm/) individually:

```
printf("Hour: %d  Min: %d  Sec: %d\n",
    tm_info->tm_hour,
    tm_info->tm_min,
    tm_info->tm_sec
);
```